# Database Query Execution Takes Too Long

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Am currently having this issue where my database query takes too long to execute and sometimes ends up failing with an error: Maximum Execution Time Exceeded... Am trying to select data from different tables that aren't directly related to each other, i.e One table is related to a table which is related to another table and so on, Some of this tables have over a thousand records, I have a feeling the structure of the different tables contributes to this headache, but I haven't been able to figure out how to reduce this execution time. Am using a CodeIgniter model where i created a function with the following sql query:

```
/**
* Get payment history based on search term
* @param string $search
* @param int $limt => default is 10
* @return mixed
**/

public function get_search_history($usertin, $search, $limit, $offset){

    $this->db->select("
            rv.name AS 'Revenue Name',rv.code AS 'Rev. Code',
            m.name AS 'MDA',m.sector AS 'Sector', b.code AS 'Bank Code',
            b.name AS 'Bank',p.amount AS 'Amount',p.channel AS 'Payment Channel',
            p.date AS 'Payment Date',p.platform AS 'Platform',p.ref AS 'Reference',
            t.tin AS 'TIN',t.active AS 'Is Active?',r.ref AS 'Receipt Reference'
        ");

    $this->db->from('revenue AS rv');
    $this->db->join('mda AS m', 'm.id = rv.mda_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('payment AS p', 'p.revenue_id = rv.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('bank AS b', 'b.id = p.bank_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('tin AS t', 't.id = p.tin_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('receipt AS r', 'r.id = p.receipt', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('t.tin', $usertin);
    $this->db->like('rv.code', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('rv.name', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('m.name', $search);
    $this->db->group_by('t.id');
    $this->db->order_by('p.date', 'ASC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return ( ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) ? $query->result_array() : 0 );

}
```

The query is supposed to retrieve a user's payment history based on a particular search term or keyword!

It's easier to see from the above query what I meant when I said "...One table is related to a table which is related to another table..." I Just can't figure out a better way of doing this. Can anyone help me out? It's given me serious headaches the past couple of days!

This is the output of the query:

```
SELECT rv.name AS 'Revenue Name', rv.code AS 'Rev. Code', m.name AS
'MDA', m.sector AS 'Sector', b.code AS 'Bank Code', b.name AS 'Bank',
p.amount AS 'Amount', p.channel AS 'Payment Channel', p.date AS 'Payment
Date', p.platform AS 'Platform', p.ref AS 'Reference', t.tin AS 'TIN',
t.active AS 'Is Active?', r.ref AS 'Receipt Reference'
FROM `revenue` AS `rv`
INNER JOIN `mda` AS `m` ON `m`.`id` = `rv`.`mda_id`
INNER JOIN `payment` AS `p` ON `p`.`revenue_id` = `rv`.`id`
INNER JOIN `bank` AS `b` ON `b`.`id` = `p`.`bank_id`
INNER JOIN `tin` AS `t` ON `t`.`id` = `p`.`tin_id`
INNER JOIN `receipt` AS `r` ON `r`.`id` = `p`.`receipt`
WHERE `t`.`tin` = '1904260529-0001'
AND  `rv`.`code` LIKE '%With%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `rv`.`name` LIKE '%With%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `m`.`name` LIKE '%With%' ESCAPE '!'
GROUP BY `t`.`id`
ORDER BY `p`.`date` ASC
LIMIT 3, 20
```

Comment: Start by making sure that all the join fields are indexed in their respective tables and that'll probably solve your problem.

Comment: @JuliePelletier When you said "join fields" do you mean columns used with the ON clause?

Comment: you have 3 like clauses -- that will be a full table scan for sure if you are prefixing with a wild card.

Comment: @aknessy: m.id, rv.id, rv.mda_id, b.id, p.bank_id, p.revenue_id, p.tin_id, p.receipt, t.id, r.id

Comment: @Hogan What's the alternative? Remove the wildcard(s) from the LIKE clause(s)?

Comment: If this all doesn't work, it's time to look at the query itself. The `group_by()` can take a long time, is it really needed for a search history? Do you need all the data that is returned? Could you use a simpler query to get the `limit()` result first and then get the other results for this limited result only?

Comment: @JuliePelletier I've just done what you advice, buh it's still taking as long a before

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Am using the group by because I want to get records for particular user based on their TIN because without it. i'd get a bunch of other unneeded records! But when you said "use a simpler query to get the limit() result first.." i don't understand, could you elaborate a little bit, please!

Comment: Can you `var_dump($query);` after it gets assigned?

Comment: @aknessy: Sorry, I cannot elaborate. You ask a MySQL question, but you give us a piece of PHP code. I have no idea what the tables in your database look like, what the columns contain, or what your query really does.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I'll edit my question to reflect the output of var_dump

Comment: http://20bits.com/article/10-tips-for-optimizing-mysql-queries-that-dont-suck

Comment: @aknessy:  Please show us the output of `explain $queryStr` in MySQL.  From what I've seen so far though, it looks like your main problem is in the design (that search query is unreasonable), but there may be place for improvement without changing the specs.

Comment: @aknessy - limit what people can search for to a list or use a full text search technology -- anything else will require a scan of all the rows.  OH, you can also cache search results and then check to see if anyone has ever search for the same thing -- this will speed up common searches.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this much tables to join frequently, there are 2 possible ways I can suggest.

#### 1. Use CodeIgniter's feature Query Caching

- You just have to enable it from database.php and have to give it a folder path where all cached queries will lie.
- Then you can create hook or something to delete and regenerate that cached queries on particular condition.

#### 2. Create View in MySQL

- You can create `View` in MySQL which will be much faster. It can be done easily right from PHPMyAdmin even.

Hope this helps.

**p.s. Try indexing proper columns.**

*Simple thumb rule is As more conditions in WHERE clause, As lower query will be*